# Using Folium HeatMapWithTime Plugin?

Tags: python, heat-map, pandas, folium

I am using pandas, and folium to replicate the following [example](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/HeatMapWithTime.ipynb), but with my CSV data to produce a heat map.

Here's what my data looks like:

[image: data]

and here is the code I am using currently:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import folium.plugins as plugins  
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


    data = [(df3).tolist() for i in range(100)]

    m = folium.Map([40., -73.], tiles='stamentoner', zoom_start=6)

    hm = plugins.HeatMapWithTime(
        data,
        index=time_index,
        auto_play=True
    )

    hm.add_to(m)
    hm.save('map.html')
```

The example works, but I cannot input my own data, as it results in errors. Would anyone know how to plot the X, and Y data from my CSV or an approach to get me started to produce a heatmap?

Comment: You should post an extract of the python code you are using, it would be easier to see what's the problem...Seems the "data" is a numpy array ?

Comment: @gisnside Thank you for your response and sorry about that, I've updated my question, but yes it is currently a numpy. I'm trying to input my CSV data instead of random points in the NP array. Any clue on how to approach this?

Comment: You can start importing your data in panda with `df = pd.read_csv(file_csv)` (see réf. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). To convert a pandas dataframe (df) to a numpy ndarray, use this code: `df=df.values`
df now becomes a numpy ndarray. Have a try getting this done, edit your code, then we will see what's the problem with folium ;)

Comment: @gisnside Thank you, I was able to plot a successful heatmap, but I would like to take it a step further in integrating time. So now I have a list of coordinates df3 and a list of dates in mm/dd/yyyy format. How would I go about displaying the heat map based on the time?

Comment: I posted an answer so it's more visible than in the comments. However, i don't have yet the answer for the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can start importing your csv data (file_csv) in panda in a dataframe (df) with a code like :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(file_csv)
```

(see réf. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

To convert a pandas dataframe (df) to a numpy ndarray, use this code:

```
df=df.values
```

df now becomes a numpy ndarray.

For the time, there's some documentation in the heat_map_with_time.py script. I have to look further (Ref. https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/folium/plugins/heat_map_withtime.py)

Form the class infos:

> **index**: Index giving the label (or timestamp) of the elements of data.
>   Should have the same length as data, or is replaced by a simple count if not specified.

From what i understand, you need to have a time index dataframe the same size as the data dataframe (or array)